# Прыгают картинки в ListView

Tags: android, listview

Вообщем есть ListView, куда через Universal Image Loader загружаются картинки , проблема в том, что при скролинге картинки пересоздаются и меняются местами. В чем проблема, кто знает?
Код getView

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {         
ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null){  
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)ctx   
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.internetlist, viewGroup, false); 
    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();            
    viewHolder.txtItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.internetlistText);   
    viewHolder.image = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.internetlistImageView1);
    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);        
    }
    else {            
    viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();        
    }
    viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();        

    //viewHolder.txtItem.setText(objects.get(position).getItems().get(0).getUrl());
    if (viewHolder.image!=null){
    new DownloadImageTask(viewHolder.image).execute(objects.get(position).getItems().get(0).getUrl());
    viewHolder.txtItem.setText(objects.get(position).getItems().get(1).getArtist());
    //ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(objects.get(position).getItems().get(0).getUrl(),viewHolder.image);

    }
    return convertView;     
    }
```

Comment: Попробуйте в логи выводить position, он изменяется так как вы ожидаете?

Comment: Position в логах не прыгает. И там кроме картинки ещё текст, он тоже не прыгает. Только картинки. Вот здесь что то пишет, только не могу понять что.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21839955/images-in-list-view-jumping-from-row-to-row

Comment: Там говориться о том что изображения грузятся не моментально и когда изображение загружено оно подсовывается вместо нужного. Как выход можно кешировать изображения. Или использовать либы Universal Image Loader or Square Picasso?

Comment: Сейчас попробую включить кеширование в Universal Image Loader

Comment: Спасибо, помогло кеширование. Еще вопрос, при скролинге список идёт рывками когда грузит картинки, потом все нормально. Можно ли как то приостанавливать загрузку во время скролинга(в Universal Image Loader)

Comment: Попробуй еще вопрос сделать, я не знаю как тебе помочь. Но может кто то другой сможет.

Comment: Очищайте imageView в адаптере, перед тем как загрузить новое изображение и не будет никаких рывков. Это происходит из-за того, что viewHolder не дает пересоздавать imageView и на то время, пока грузится новое изображение, старое остается висеть и получается такой неприятный эффект